# Sass nesting of h1 within a .title selector

Tags: sass

I have tried sass

```
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    // more title styles
    &h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

Resulting css is:

```
.titleh1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    // more title styles
}
.titleh1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Is there anyway I can keep the h1 nested in the .title to give css output like this?

```
.titleh1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    // more title styles
}
h1.title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need [the @at-root directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_at-root__at-root) to jump back out of your nested selector:

```
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    // more title styles

    @at-root {
      h1#{&} {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Seth, that compiles to `h1 .title { font-size: 30px; }`, I'm looking for something that compiles to `h1.title { font-size: 30px; }`  (no space between h1 and .title)

Comment: @Davey Change the `h1 &` to `h1#{&}`.